# how to add a function to a lib class without overriding it

Tags: c++, overriding

I've a case in which I need to add some functions to a game engine class I'm using for a VR project without overriding the class it self:

The engine class name is `AnnwaynPlayer` that contains many useful methods to control the player, now I'm in the networking phase so I need to add 2 extra methods to this lib class which are `setActive()` and `setConnected()`, what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: sub classing may be an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't touch the class itself then you probably want to use inheritance.  This is one of the main goals of object-oriented programming -- to be able to add/change the behavior of an existing class without altering it.  So you want something like:

```
class MyAnnwaynPlayer : public AnnwaynPlayer {
public:
    void setActive();
    void setConnected();
    // ...
}
```

Now, things will be fine if `AnnwaynPlayer` has a `virtual` destructor.  If it doesn't and your `MyAnnwaynPlayer` class has a non-trivial destructor then you have to wary of using an instance of `MyAnnwaynPlayer` through a pointer (be it raw or smart) of base class `AnnwaynPlayer`.  When a pointer of the type is deleted, it will not chain through a call to your `MyAnnwaynPlayer` destructor.

Comment: this is what i need, thx for the help :D, so now I'll just call MyAnnwaynPlayer and be able to use all the stuff in anwaynPlayer with my extra methods :D

Answer (score 2):

Also consider [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) if you only need access to the public API of the base class. It's safer than inheritance, because you don't necessarily know the right class to inherit from in cases where the implementation returns something ultimately unspecified (like an internal derived class).

In essence, this would look like this:

```
namespace AnnwaynNamespace {
void setActive(AnnwaynPlayer& p);
void setConnected(AnnwaynPlayer& p);
};
```

And you could call them without `using` those functions (or the namespace), because ADL.

```
void wherever(AnnwaynNamespace::AnnwaynPlayer& p) {
    setActive(p);
}
```

So `setActive`, etc, become part of the actual public API of the class, without involving any inheritance.